# Access denied, with correct credientials

Tags: php, mysql, terminal

I'm using [this](http://www.spikaapp.com/install-backend.php), and when I enter `$ sudo mysql -uroot -e <<EOSQL "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('yourpassword') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"` And then `EOSQL`. I get this error.

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

I am using a password, and username. But I'm not sure why I get this error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't appear to pass the existing password for the root user?

Comment: try `sudo mysql -u root -p ` then enter your password

Comment: So do that before I enter the rest? @SamD

Comment: yes. -p prompts for password

Comment: And for password would I enter my computer password or my DB password? @SamD

Comment: your mysql db password for the root user

Comment: I get the same error still. @SamD

Answer (score 0):

Just add key -p to your command and add space after -u (should be -u root)

Comment: Like this? `sudo mysql -u root -e -p <<EOSQL "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('yourpassword') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"`

Comment: Why to ask? Just try. But yes, like this.